# Applescript - check terminal password requirement?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, applescript

I am writing an applescript.
I use the "do shell script" with the sudo-command or other commands that need a password.
When I use these commands sometimes it requires the Userpassword but sometimes not.

How can I check whether it needs the password or not?
And how can I pass it to the the shell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- The man page of the command line interface describes if the password is required.
- `do shell script` provides optional parameters `user name` and `password` to pass the credentials

PS: You **must not** use `sudo` when passing the `password` parameter

Comment: tell application "Terminal"
 activate
 delay 20
 do shell script "sudo nano /etc/sudoers" user name "user" password "pw" with administrator privileges
end tell

But I get this error:

error "Terminal got an error: Error opening terminal: unknown." number 1

Comment: `do shell script` is for running shell scripts without Terminal.app. Once again: **You MUST NOT use the `sudo` prefix when passing the `password` parameter**